# Xcode cant find file in explore while file exits in finder

Tags: ios, xcode

New to this Xcode sh*t(sorry for that, but really pissed off by Xcode)

The thing is I could find there should be a specific file by `grep` or finder, but in the Xcode project, the file does not exist here:

[image]

[image]

Here is the result with `grep` in the project folder
And here is the project hierarchy in Xcode.
They are mismatch!

Can't apple just make this Xcode sh*t right? How could I find this file in Xcode's folder? Thanks

Comment: In my case, recreating the file solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if that file exist into Copy Bundle Resources.

Click "Your project name" from Xcode left sidebar then select your main target and go to Build phases tab and inside that go to Copy Bundle Resources and check whether that file exists or not.